# How to overclock the Raspberry Pi with Kali Linux?

Tags: overclocking

I've just installed Kali Linux on my SD card that I use with Raspberry. This new OS I think is very good, but at the installation I don't have the opportunity to overclock as it is possible with Raspbian so I'd like to try to check differences. How could I do?

Comment: I don't have Kali. But is there a `/boot/` folder with a `config.txt` file in it? Alternatively if you put the SD card in a normal computer, is there a `fat32` partition?

Comment: Yes there is the /boot/ folder but is empty

Comment: Add the `config.txt` file and put some overclocking settings in there [Overclocking Settings](http://elinux.org/RPi_config.txt#Overclocking_options) and see if that works.

Comment: config.txt is read by the hardware, afaik, so that should be the solution independent of your OS

Comment: @krs013 : Why do you believe "config.txt is read by the hardware"? Sounds a bit specious to me.

Comment: Guess I should have sourced that: "The Raspberry Pi config.txt file is read by the GPU before the ARM core is initialised. It can be used to set various system configuration parameters." (http://elinux.org/RPiconfig)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While the post above me shows you how to install raspi-config, it won't actually get the config.txt file working.  Simply making /boot/config.txt puts the file in the wrong place for the Kali install.  I followed the instructions here: http://rageweb.info/2013/11/07/bootconfig-txt-in-kali/ and it worked for me.  The problem is that /boot/ isn't actually the boot partition, so you are placing the file in the wrong place (even though it seems right).

Comment: Here there is the solution to install raspi-config http://rageweb.info/2013/03/21/raspi-config-in-kali/ but I still have problem with overclock :S

Comment: The correct path seems to be `/dev/mmcblk0p1/` instead of `/boot/`. The first is the actual boot partition in Kali.

Comment: @Mast No, the correct path by from that blog would be `/fat32/`.  `/dev/mmcblk0p1` is a *device node* representing the partition that is being `mount`ed on the `/fat32` directory (the "mount point"); after it's mounted, you can access the partition through the mount point directory.

Comment: If you then want to use `raspi-config` as per @AlessioMTX 's comment, you would have to edit `/usr/bin/raspi-config` and change `CONFIG=/boot/config.txt` (about line 9) to `CONFIG=/fat32/config.txt`.

Comment: @goldilocks `/fat32/` is an arbitrary name here, as stated in the link. Wouldn't that inverse your comment?

Comment: @Mast No, that's the whole point.  Yes, `/fat32` is arbitrary, but so is `/boot`.   `/dev/mmcblk0p2` gets mounted exactly the same way on Raspbian automatically when the system starts up; there is a line in `/etc/fstab` for it.   You could do the same thing on Kali (have it mounted automatically) by adding a similar line to `fstab`: `/dev/mmcblk0p2   /fat32   vfat   defaults    0   2`.    The problem is that `/boot` is already used for something else on Kali.   It generally is on linux, sort of.   Raspbian was customized that way.

Answer (score 3):

While you may not be able to install raspi-config, you should still be able to create the file `/boot/config.txt`. Once `config.txt` is in `/boot/`, [add any required parameters](http://elinux.org/RPiconfig).

In your case, check out some of the [overclocking options in the eLinux wiki](http://elinux.org/RPiconfig#Overclocking). As always is the case with overclocking, be careful!